# Will there ever be a Meet-up?

Tags: discussion

Just putting this out there. What are the chances of an official M.Y. (or J.SE) meet-up/tweet-up of sorts?

Comment: Every Wednesday :)

Comment: Why don't you flesh out what you have in mind? As @ShmuelBrill points out, we have Parashat Hashavua' Chat every Wednesday, which is sort of like a tweet-up, I think. (I'm not a regular twitterer and can only make an educated guess as to what a tweet-up is.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses I probably shouldn't have called for a tweet-up. A tweet-up is really the same thing as a meet-up, both meant to be done in physical space, just that it involves Twitter users who regularly communicate solely in that medium but want to meet face to face.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill I'm wondering if we'll ever get a chance to meet in person.

Comment: @IsaacMoses How about a Shabbaton, or a Yom 'Iyun or a regionally organized lunch (NY-MD meet up in Philly; Detroit-Columbus meet up in Cleveland; Chaifa-Jlm meet up in TA; etc.)?

Comment: Seth, shall I invoke Herzl's most famous quotation?

Comment: @SethJ, I'm guessing there are enough NYC users that it would be inconvenient for them to go to Philly to accommodate Philadelphians and Marylanders.

Comment: @msh210 I was just giving possible examples of regional compromise locations. There might just be enough in Yerushalayim to demand that everyone in Israel meet up there as well. Or Chicago, or LA. I'm just throwing out some ideas for smaller groups, if a big international Shabbaton is something too ambitious for the time being (y'know, until we grow a bit bigger).

Comment: This question now has me wondering how I would find out about other J.SE folks in cities I might visit (or my own for that matter).  For example, if I go to Yerushalayim for a week this summer, where should I ask about possibly meeting people?  Chat?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog

Comment: @MonicaCellio, you could try posting on chat when you're going to a city where you think you might find fellow community members. Generally, though, SE's really not set up for facilitating private offline communications, by design.

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1635/759

Answer (score 8):

The following users are interested in getting pinged by other Yodeyans who happen to be visiting their locales. One way to ping them would be to find them in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam). Another would be to comment on this post, with an @ping of their username. It's up to you to figure out how to meet up in the real world.

- [Isaac Moses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses) - Silver Spring, MD
- [Daniel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1713/daniel) - Atlanta
- [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio) - Pittsburgh
- [Noach miFrankfurt](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/4504/noach-mi-frankfurt) - Boston
- [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch) - Tel Aviv and surroundings
- [רבות](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16354/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA) - Toronto and surroundings (A number of other Toronto Mi Yodeya participants that I know offline may also be interested in meeting you...)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what the plans are for a network-wide meetup, but don't wait for us! There's nothing keeping this community from putting together your own events and meet-ups through something like http://meetups.com. This community has long since had the cohesion and organization to pull something like this off, at least in a limited geographic area. Just gotta figure out what/where that is.

Answer (score 4):

One could always do a google hangout :). I don't know if I'll join, but it's an idea for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

The StackExchange folks are planning a meetup for technology sites this April 28, 2012 as outlined in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/). But they did say in a footnote:

> For those of you who aren’t programmers, hackers or designers – fear not! We haven’t forgotten you; stay tuned for news of a possible network-wide event later this year.

So it seems the chances are pretty good!